# Is etale sheafification of algebraic K-theory related to analytic continuation of the zeta function?

Tags: nt.number-theory, at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

The Riemann zeta function can be recovered from algebraic K-theory and the Borel regulator. Analytic continuation is therefore a reasonable proceedure to do to Algebraic K-theory. How can we understand analytic continuation in this context? Is this related to etale sheafification?